# A linear operator $T = \frac{d^{2}}{dx^{2}}x^{2}$

Tags: derivatives

During the course of my own research, I have been interested in the 
linear operator
\[
T \equiv \frac{d^{2}}{dx^{2}}x^{2}
\]
and using $T$ repeatedly to the function $(A + xB)^{s}$, that is,
\[
T^{n}[(A + xB)^{s}],
\]
where $A$ is any positive real number, $B$ any complex number,
and $s$ any real that is not an integer.

I am wondering if there exists any absolute constant $c$ satisfying
\[
|T^{n}[ (A + xB)^{s} ]| \leq  c |\frac{d^{2n}}{dx^{2n}}x^{s + 2}B^{s}|,
\]
for all $n$. Note that the right expression is just that of the left
with $A = 0$.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you please clarify how, exactly, $T$ acts on a twice-differentiable function $f$?

Comment: That's, T[f] multiplies f by x^2 and then takes the derivative twice.